# Why is path to the interpreter hardcoded in ELF executables?

Tags: linux, elf

(This is a general question and not a complaint -- there is probably a good explanation for this.)

For a compiled executable, why is path to the interpreter hard-coded into the binary as opposed to letting the operating system decide? I.e shouldn't the interpreter be derivable from the executable's format (e.g ELF) and architecture (x86-64).

The interpreter path can be seen when running `file /path/to/some-executable`:

```bash
some-executable: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=acd1829414c2843215bd10ed75a0fe486fce288e, not stripped
```

---

To ensure the interpreter path string really exists in the binary, then `strings -t x /path/to/some-executable | head` shows it to be at byte 0x270: `270 /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`, inspecting the file with `readelf -l /path/to/some-executable` shows the same offset for the interpreter.

Comment: You might want to use `strings` or a hex editor limited by head to show the path is actually in the file or some people might treat `file` as a red herring because it's such a giant stack of heuristics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The attributes available in [the ELF header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format#File_header) (other than the pointer to the dynamic linker itself) *aren’t* sufficient to determine the appropriate dynamic linker. The dynamic linker is also tied to the C library against which the compiler was built, and thus for example a 64-bit x86 binary on Linux built using the GNU C library will probably [fail if loaded by the musl dynamic linker](https://www.musl-libc.org/faq.html):

> Binary compatibility is much more limited, but it will steadily increase with new versions of musl. At present, some glibc-linked shared libraries can be loaded with musl, but all but the simplest glibc-linked applications will fail if musl is dropped-in in place of `/lib/ld-linux.so.2`.

The choice of dynamic linker also governs how shared libraries are discovered, so it isn’t even really possible to only specify a dynamic linker by name without a path, and rely on a linker-style algorithm to find the appropriate linker. It would be possible to use another approach, but it would have to be implemented in the kernel, so it’s much easier just to hard-code it in each binary.

Comment: I take it that the path `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` is a (reasonably) common standard location across many Linux distributions?

Comment: It’s *the* location of the dynamic linker on glibc-based x86-64 Linux platforms.

Answer (score 0):

Specifying an interpreter against a standard path you expect it to exist at or using /usr/bin/env in its place has a logn history in 'nix systems.  Just look at the hash-bang line starting most scripts.  Since there's no real OS concept of a file type, just putting the expected path or the interpreter or linker into the file is the old standard solution that was never replaced.

Comment: Right, but aren't hash-bang scripts (provided by binfmt_script.c) or custom interpreters (binfmt_misc.c) there to provide "escape hatches" to get out of the normal flow? I.e I would have assumed ELF to be the normal interpreter flow where specifying a path wouldn't be required.

Comment: Given that the path to interpreter is embedded, I can pretty much customize every executable with patchelf to run in some arbitrary way.